# Rectangle.overlaps() Method not working [LibGDX]

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
Iterator<Rectangle> iter = incomingCars.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle incomingCar = iter.next();
        incomingCar.y -= score/2+200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        }
         if(incomingCar.overlaps(car)) {
              iter.remove();
           }
    }
```

Followed a tutorial for this very closely and it's still messing up, there is 0 detecting/collision being detected between the two Rectangles.

```
public void create() {


    car = new Rectangle();
    car.x = 180;
    car.y = 0;
    car.height = 172;
    car.width = 100;


    incomingCars = new Array<Rectangle>();

}
private void spawnCar() {
        int lane;
        Rectangle incomingCar = new Rectangle();
        lane = MathUtils.random(0, 2);
        if (lane == 0) {
            incomingCar.x = 30;
        }
        if (lane == 1) {
            incomingCar.x = 180;
        }
        if (lane == 2) {
            incomingCar.x = 330;
        }
        incomingCar.y = 1000;
        incomingCars.add(incomingCar);
```

So I'll try to debug this stuff now, but I feel like im missing something slightly important. gotta add some extra details here, not sure what to say, I guess i'll try check if the cars are actually colliding in any way.

Comment: Can you give a short but complete example, including creating the two rectangles with hard-coded locations and sizes?

Comment: Have you debugged this and checked the actual values of incomingCar and car to see if they really overlap?

Comment: @JonSkeet Added extra code.

Comment: @xp500, good idea i'll give that a shot now, but in terms of what I can see they perfectly overlap, they're the same sizes, so they should be colliding

Comment: @CodingNub Now that you say that, I don't see where you are setting the height and width of the incomingCars, acording to the docs, they are set to 0 with using the constructor you used.

Comment: @xo500 Aaaaaand im an idiot >.> Thought I put those in, must have completely gone over my head, thanks!